# Convert from nvarchar to datetime in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have field data datetime stored in varchar type.
I tried to convert them to datetime but I failed.

```
declare @mydate nvarchar(50) = '23-JUL-18 10.47.03.003000 AM' 

select convert(datetime,@mydate,103)
```

Comment: As per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017 , "103" is "DD/MM/YYYY" format, so this will not match your string. In fact I don't think any of the preset formats will match this particular string. I would be far better not to store dates as text in the first place.

Comment: That's similar to a VMS date.

Comment: Please provide your required format here as an example.

Comment: @AbdurRahman OP wants to convert it into a datetime object, not a particular format

Answer (score 4):

Here is a fairly clean approach using `TRY_CONVERT`:

```
SELECT
    TRY_CONVERT(DATETIME, LEFT(@mydate, 9)) +
    TRY_CONVERT(DATETIME, REPLACE(RIGHT(STUFF(@mydate, 19, 7, ''), 11), '.', ':')) AS dt;
```

[image]

### Demo

But using queries like this is no way to live, at least not if you have to look at this code on a daily basis.  Instead, maybe try to see if you can get your incoming data into a format which SQL Server can directly consume.

Comment: Much cleaner than my attempt. :)

Comment: @Larnu I also previously was using `CONVERT` explicitly, the old school approach, but kept getting beaten out by answers using `TRYCONVERT`.  So, I'm "getting with the program."

Answer (score 1):

No Style codes match the date format you have. Against a tally table, the following returns no results:

```
DECLARE @mydate nvarchar(50) = '23-JUL-18 10.47.03.003000 AM';
WITH
test AS
    (SELECT TOP 500
            TRY_CONVERT(datetime, @mydate, v.N) AS Conv,
            N
     FROM dbo.vTally v)
SELECT *
FROM test
WHERE test.Conv IS NOT NULL;
```

Provided that the format is **always** `dd-mon-yy hh.mi.ss.mmmmmmAM` this this should work:

```
SELECT CONVERT(datetime2(6),SUBSTRING(@MyDate,4,3) + N' ' + LEFT(@MyDate,2) + N' 20' + SUBSTRING(@MyDate,8,2) + N' ' + REPLACE(SUBSTRING(@MyDate,11,8),N'.',N':') + REPLACE(RIGHT(@MyDate,10),N' ',N''),109)
```

Answer (score 1):

Combine with LEFT and REPLACE and your attempt was almost there -

```
DECLARE @mydate nvarchar(50) = '23-JUL-18 10.47.03.003000 AM' 
SELECT LEFT(REPLACE(@mydate, '.', ':'), 18)
SELECT TRY_CONVERT(DATETIME,LEFT(REPLACE(@mydate, '.', ':'), 18),103)
```

Comment: That loses the time though.

Answer (score 0):

Until someone can offer a better approach, this seems to work
I would definitely recommend waiting for a better solution before you accept this one.

```
DECLARE  @mydate    NVARCHAR(50) = '23-JUL-18 10.47.03.003000 AM' 
        ,@changing  NVARCHAR(50)

SET @changing = STUFF(@mydate, CHARINDEX('.', @mydate), 1, ':')
SET @changing = STUFF(@changing, CHARINDEX('.', @changing), 1, ':')


SELECT CAST(CAST(@changing AS DATETIME2) AS DATETIME)
```